WinEdt and multiple text selection and formatting
I have a very large text and i want to repeatedly select a large number of keywords and phrases inside the text and then to apply to them, the \emph style. Is there a way (at least) to select more than one words and phrases as in Microsoft Word in order then to apply the formatting? At the moment I select each single item one after the other, and then apply the \emph text style, a procedure that is time consuming. Can I apply the \emph style via a shortcut? I did not find anything related .. I use WinEdt 10. Thanks a lot.

As a bypass, you could: (A) find an editor, which provides this, (B) copy your large text and run such a macro there, (C) copy back to WinEdt. // You can, of course, replace the cop action by saving and opening a/the .tex file. // I suggest you add an (artificial) text example, which shows at leat two such phrases, so we can understand similarities and differences. This would be necessary e.g. when trying regular expressions on your phrases.
